# How to get particular Id by using getElementById

Tags: javascript, php

This is my code

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['taskBtnn'])){
    $responseCode =200;
    if($responseCode == 200){?> 
    <script>
    function uniqueId(id){
    var e = document.getElementById(id); 
    e.innerHTML="approved";  
    }     
    </script> 
<?php }?>
```

This is my button

```
<button type="submit"  name="taskBtnn" id="<?php echo $btn1; ?>" value="<?php echo $catData['id'];?>" class="btn btn-info btn-sm togglebtn" onclick="uniqueId(<?php echo $btn1; ?>)">Active</button>
```

First, I applied that if a button is click then it shows loading time after that its innerHTML change to approved.
Here is my code for loading time

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){   
       $(document).on("click", ".btn", function(){   
         $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>");   
});
  });
</script>
```

Now, I am trying to change the button innerHTML when it gets responseCode 200, but my code is not working..

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In your php, I would just echo the html you want inserted, then instead of actually posting to the php, do an ajax call to it and then in the success, you can append your html

Comment: Just check if ```var e = document.getElementById(id); ``` if this e is available when this code is run. Maybe it is not visible.

Comment: @pete: Yes, by using ajax I can do it, but my task is to do without ajax..So is it possible without ajax?

Comment: @ishmeet: If i write document.getElementBy(id).value; then I am getting current Id.

Comment: No, you would need to put the data directly into the page when it refreshes after the postback - I mean, you could run the script, but there would be no point as the page is reloading anyway, so you may as well use your php to enter the text directly into the place you want it

Comment: If I am doing it without function, then script is working but only problem occurs that it is taking last id..But I want the selected Id. So, is there any way to get selected id.               <script>
    var e = document.getElementById('<?php echo $btn1;?>'); 
    e.innerHTML="approved";       
    </script>